# A big trouble with Greece Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen-visas

I have a plan to attend conference held in Greece April 2020. I have already purchased return air ticket. However, I have been informed by Greece embassy in Bangkok that obtaining visa for Greece needs to wait for a long queue (until the end of April. I didn't expect this to happen (my big mistake that I didn't check before purchasing air ticket). I have written email to the Greece embassy in Bangkok, but get no response.

My friend suggested me to go for Italy visa instead. Would it be possible to enter Greece with Italy Schengen visa?

Comment: You are allowed to go to Greece with a Schengen visa issued by Italy, but to get Schengen visa for Italy you would have to lie.  If you are found out, you likely won't be able to get a Schengen visa from *any* consulate for a long time.

Comment: If you intend to holiday (or find something else to do) in Italy for a longer time than you plan to be in Greece, then it would be legitimate to get an Italy visa. But since you've already booked your travel, that might be difficult now.

Comment: A very general rule: never book non-refundable tickets (and hotels) before having a visa.

Answer (score 5):

> Would it be possible to enter Greece with Italy Schengen visa?

A Schengen visa is valid for the whole Schengen area.

However, you are required to apply to the country which can be considered your primary destination.  Or if you stay for an equal amount of time in more than one  country, then the country whos border you will cross first.

See:
https://eeas.europa.eu/sites/eeas/files/frequently_asked_questions_en.pdf

As your purpose is to attend a conference in Greece and you have no business or personal need to travel to Italy at all then the Italian authorities would reject your application.

Comment: The smallest of points, significant only to search algorithms: the term used in the Schengen Visa Code is "main destination."  A slightly more significant point: it would be more precise to say "required" than "expected."

Comment: The answer could also be improved with a link to some authoritative source for the claim.  Nonetheless, the claim is correct, and the answer is remarkably clear and concise.  I have already upvoted it.